# How to get Flextable to output to pdf?

Tags: r, pdf, flextable

I am having the same problem as Joe Crozier.  I cannot get flextables to show up in my pdf output.  I would have commented on his thread but I am not allowed to being new.  I actually tried the exact example that was given as his answer and flextable in that example did not print to the pdf file either.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(flextable)
```

```
ft <- flextable(head(airquality))
ft <- autofit(ft)
theme_vader(ft)
```

Could it possibly be the LaTeX package that I am using?  Does this work for some and not others?  I was using MiKTeX and just uninstalled it and used Tinytex instead with the same result.  The code prints to the pdf but the table does not.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I figured it out.  I thought I would leave an answer in case someone else is struggling with this.  I needed to update my version of Flextable.  I had just reinstalled R Studio a couple of days ago on a new computer and figured most things should be up-to-date, but when I checked my Flextable package was prior to the one with the fix for this issue.  I installed version 0.6.1 and it now works.